# Lifecycle when pausing AND rotating

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I've got an app that is complete, apart from the lifecycle that, guiltily, I left as last.
Things seem to work good in all cases, but one:

- When I **pause** the app by pressing the power button, it correctly pauses and restarts when resuming.
- When I **rotate** the screen it correctly resizes.
- When I **pause AND THEN rotate** the screen, its behaviour is different and the app resets.

Now, obviously it's a problem of my internal code, but to help me in the debugging, I would like to understand what's the difference between the three lifecycles. Or better, if the THIRD example is some how different from the first two.

With debugging I saw that all of three do this (I resemble by mind, I hope to be right):

- `onSaveInstanceState()`
- `onPause()`
- `onStop()`
- `onStart()`
- `onResume()`

Is it right? Or do I miss some lifecycle steps in the third example, above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please specify what you mean by *the app resets*.

When you press the power button, most likely your app *stops*. That's why you see `onStart()` being called after *stopping* (not: *pausing*) your app.

Given that, is it really the case that the third scenario you describe is a combination of the first two? In other words, how do you *pause* your app in the third scenario?

**Update** Regarding your comment: There is a difference between your Activity being *stopped* and your Activity being *destroyed*.

Rotation is a configuration change. In this scenario, your Activity is going to be destroyed and re-created. You can handle this case separately if you must (it depends) through the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` callback and the `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` method. Android *will* call `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `onDestroy()` in this order, and then continue with `onCreate()` etc and it will *not* handle any events in the meantime so that they won't get lost.

Most likely, some of your code is located in the wrong callback, such that in the third scenario, something does not get initialized/attached/... This is really hard to tell without the code *and* the exception (if it is an exception).

I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Complete your understanding of the lifecycle and be precise (creation, start, restart, resume, pause, stop, destroy)
- Complete your code to override the other lifecycle callbacks as well with log messages (don't forget to call the super class' callback) and analyze pause, stop, rotation and combinations
- Identify the point of the crash
- Analyze the life cycle of the objects involvedd in the crash in conjunction with the Activity lifecycle

Or you can post some code and the exception here, of course.

**Update 2** I have made a test on an AVD. I have observed the following:

When the AVD is in landscape orientation, and I press the power button, my app receives a configuration change to portrait orientation (presumably because the portrait-orientation-only lock screen takes over). Pressing power again and unlocking the AVD, the app receives a configuration change again back to landscape orientation.

While not solving your issue, it goes to show that code must be carefully placed in the respective callbacks, because in the case above, while being re-created, the Activity will still not be *shown*.

Drop me a comment if you update your question.

Comment: All the tests were made on the emulator. In the third test I press the power button, wait for the screen to be locked, rotate the screen and unlock it. Obviously there's some difference between this scenario and the one in which I simply rotate the screen or simply lock the screen and unlock it back.

In the first two scenarios, I always find that the onStart() is run, so I suppose that the activity is destroyed on all three. But why is there a difference?

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi I have updated my answer. -- Geez, I have no idea why someone downvoted it. Probably someone who hasn't mastered this topic. Or someone clicked on the wrong arrow.

Comment: Your answer doesn't definitely deserve a downvote, I up-voted to compensate :) and of course because it's a good answer.

Comment: Of course I have to pass all the code to find what is put in the wrong place, I didn't want a precise help about my code because it would be too complex to post it and - obviously - something i prefer to fix understanding how to fix it, instead of just asking someone "fix me" :) I think that the point is in the fact that some how the activity is destroyed in the 3rd scenario and not in the first two. Although I don't know why this should create a difference in my app, your suggestions have been very useful, thanks.

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi Please be aware that your Activity _is_ being destroyed in the second scenario as well. -- If you give me a hint about what the exception says, I may be able to give you a tip -- actually, there are a few subtle aspects which can cause this.

Comment: What I am working on is a game. You can get it if you want on the market, it's not a secret: it.beppi.wooords . I submitted that app to Samsung that has pointed me that the lifecycle was not developed (indeed, I forgot it :) ) with two defects: power button does not send the game to pause, and the sequence power+rotation+power resets the boardgame. In the version I'm going soon to upload, the first problem is fixed, there are also some minor changes that help managing rotation and resizeing due to ad banners. The second problem is still alive, although it would be fixed with Mayu's suggestion.

Comment: by "resets the boardgame" I mean that the game acts as if it was restarted, so it's totally an error of mine :) there's no real exception or error. I just lacked the complete understanding of why the third scenario is different from the first two.

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi Mayu's solution may fix orientation change, but you'll still have the same problem when someone pauses your game and changes the system language, I presume. -- With the given information, I can unfortunately only say that it sounds like your game logic is based on an assumption which only holds true most of the time. I have updated my answer with a piece of information I found surprising myself (came across this when testing my app against your scenario).

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can check the **[documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)** regarding Managing the Activity life cycles in android .

Answer (score 0):

When orientation changes Activity is re-created.

Add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to your `activity` in the manifest.

Comment: The OP says he already manages screen rotation correctly. Please elaborate on how your suggestion is going to improve his situation under these circumstances.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. But what I don't understand if rotating the screen AFTER having set the app in pause is some how different from rotating the screen while the app is running.

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi Please _don't_ try this. It is bad practice.

Comment: Yes I saw that the documentation suggests not to do this, I will take it as a last resort as the deocumentation itself states :)